# Handling requests to ASPNET Core API asynchronously

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, .net-core

I am upgrading and old .net framework API to a aspnet core web API. The API receives Get and Post requests, does some computation and accesses a database, and then returns a Json string.

I have converted all the lower level functionality of the code to .net core, but when doing some load testing, the new code is much slower than the older implementation. I suspect this is due to the highest level of the old code which used Unity containers to run threads asynchronously.

My project is using .NET core 2.2, and is running locally on my machine as of now, being hosted by kestrel.

I have already looked into many of the Asynchronous practices in C# such as using Tasks, and await/async keywords. I may have used these incorrectly though. In my understanding, await is used for when there are synchronous tasks that don't need the return of a certain function immediately, but there seems not to be a use-case for that in my code.

Basically, I believe that my individual API call response is fast, but that the code is blocking multiple API calls from running at the same time. I proved this by making the API immediately return an empty json string, and the response is still a lot slower than the older code which does database access among other things.

I have also tried modifying the configureKestrel options in my Program.cs and initializing classes as singletons in the Startup.cs, but it still has no effect on the throughput.

Controller:

```cs
public class ExecuteController : Controller
{
    private readonly var vars;

    public ExecuteController(var vars)
    {
        //Dependency Injection constructor
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("route")]
    public Result Execute([FromBody] ExecuteParams parameters)
    {
        ExecuteJobResult res = vars.ExecuteJob(parameters);
        return new Result { answer = res };
    }
```

Again, the actual functionality of the individual ExecuteJob is not relevant because when returning the empty string at the start of the method it was still slow. I need to find a way to have all the API calls to this method to happen at the same time and not be queued.

Link to Repository with code that only returns an empty string:
[Repo](https://bitbucket.org/ad185328/tester/src/master/)
You will need to have dotnet installed to run it

As you can see below, when running the empty string gatling (load) test I get something like this:
[Slow Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ex6lh.png)

This is what the old code looked like, and as you can see the responses over time is smooth and does drop down to 0 ever
[Fast Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a65op.png)

Comment: Is session state disabled?

Comment: Please be specific when you post the code and mention about asynchronous programming. Code does not show any reason why it is slow that anyone can here suggest you to improve.

Comment: @StephenCleary I currently have it disabled

Comment: @AviKenjale I believe that the ExecuteJob method itself does not need to be sped up, but that the calls to the method (through the url route) are not being handled asynchronously

Comment: Please post a minimal reproducible example. `returning the empty string at the start of the method it was still slow` is especially odd, since [ASP.NET Core has been benchmarked at just under 7 **million** plaintext requests per second](https://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/#section=data-r18&hw=ph&test=plaintext).

Comment: @StephenCleary I have edited the post to include a link to a repo, and have also added images of my load tests

Comment: The WebAPI documentation for .NET Core 2.2 states "Don't create a web API controller by deriving from the `Controller` class." and tells you to derive from `ControllerBase` instead.

Comment: Forgot to mention in my previous comment as to why they recommend that: deriving from Controller pulls in everything you need to make a full fledged MVC controller (web page rendering and all that jazz) rather than just a Web API controller.

Comment: The reference for what @Powerlord said is here: [Create web APIs with ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#controllerbase-class)